# How to load a json file with unit ML test examples into jmeter http request payload

Tags: json, parsing, request, jmeter, loading

I have an endpoint that serves a ML model and I want to perform load testing on it. I'm using Jmeter 4.0 and its UI to construct a simple plan test. With 1 thread group that loops  for a given duration and continuosly performs https requests.

How do I parse multiple test examples into the payload of a http request, one by one and in json format. These examples are contained in a json file called samples.json. The nested structure is the following:

```
{ "dataset": [
    {"id": 1,
    "in":[
     {
        "Feature1": 8.9
        "Feature2":7.1
     }],
    "out": "Class1",
    },
    {"id": 2,
    "in":[
     {
        "Feature1": 3.2
        "Feature2":5.1
     }],
    "out": "Class1",
    }]
}
```

IMPORTANT: I do not know the number of attributes a priori, so I need to retrieve them from the **in** key as that may change for other types of models, therefore I can't make use of harcoded jmeter variables, similar to what it's used  in the *CSV Config Set add-on*, where they need to specify the variables names for each column of the csv file

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you're gonna use the values from JSON in the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, however this is how you can parse your `samples.json` file and get `in` values from it in the [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

```
new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File('samples.json')).dataset.each { entry ->
    entry.get('in').each { feature ->
        feature.each { value ->
            log.info(value.key + '=' + value.value)
        }
    }
}
```

The above code basically prints the keys and respective values into *jmeter.log* file

[image: JMeter Parse JSON]

But you can easily amend it to store the values into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), write them into a CSV file, set HTTP Request sampler to use them on the fly, etc.

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
- [Apache JMeter API](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html)

Comment: I want to fill the body data of a http request with the field in (all the features in that format), but I want to walk through all the in fields in my samples.json and fill a single http request and keep iterating, so a single unit test per request. Thanks for the response anyway! very appreciated